# Storage of Range Values after .Find

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

This is part of a bigger code that both filters based on input text and then creates subtotals out of the values associated with warranty subtypes, this is applied to several different sheets and it all works.

There is the possibility of many different Warranties subtypes.

I check for each one individually, first for an exact match case for "WarrantyPrefA Total" (this should be on the AJ Column).

- If it exists, I want to store that range value inside a variable(GaRangeID), so I can apply an offset of that range to grab the two numerical values present in other columns and paste it on another Workbook.
- If it doesn't exist, I want to terminate that find, and find another exact match case.

My guess is I'm messing up the `.Find` inner syntax to search the correct range.

```vb
Dim GaRangeID As Range
Dim WBModeloA1 As Worksheet
Dim WBModeloA2 As Worksheet
Set WBModeloA1 = Workbooks("ModeloAnalisis.xlsm").Sheets("Cartera 1")
Set WBModeloA2 = Workbooks("ModeloAnalisis.xlsm").Sheets("Cartera 3")

'GPB

 Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lastrow As Long

    strSearch = "WarrantyPrefA Total"
    lastrow = WBevoDeuM.Range("AJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Set GaRangeID = WBevoDeuM.Range("AJ1", "AJ" & lastrow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not GaRangeID Is Nothing Then

       WBModeloA1.Range("E67") = GaRangeID.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1")
       WBModeloA1.Range("E67").Value = WBModeloA1.Range("E67").Value / 1000

       WBModeloA2.Range("H91") = GaRangeID.Offset(0, -21).Range("A1")
       WBModeloA2.Range("H91").Value = WBModeloA2.Range("H91").Value / 1000

    Else
    End If

'GPA

   Set GaRangeID = Cells.Find(What:="WarrantyPrefB Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
   :=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not GaRangeID Is Nothing Then

   WBModeloA1.Range("E65") = GaRangeID.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1")
   WBModeloA1.Range("E65").Value = WBModeloA1.Range("E65").Value / 1000

   WBModeloA2.Range("H90") = GaRangeID.Offset(0, -21).Range("A1")
   WBModeloA2.Range("H90").Value = WBModeloA2.Range("H90").Value / 1000

Else
End If
```

The reason I show it repeats the same structure but with another find afterwards is because I used to have the "find" part defined in another way.

**The following way properly pastes the subtotals onto the other workbook**, but I discarded it since it always sets the GaRangeID as the active cell, when the search gets nothing, the active cell remains as the old subtotal found, and so it just pastes the values of WarrantyA onto B.

```
Cells.Find(What:="WarrantyPrefB Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
    :=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Set GaRangeID = ActiveCell
```

Comment: `Cells.Find()` with no worksheet qualifier will default to the ActiveSheet - that can cause problems, so the first step would be to update your code to always use specific worksheets/ranges when referencing any Range/Cells.  In this case `worksheetReference.Range("AJ:AJ").find()`

Comment: first of all, thx for the reply, I continued trying to solve it and I did came to that same solution, I added `Dim WBevoDeuM As Worksheet` defined it and `Set GaRangeID = WBevoDeuM.Range("AJ:AJ11000").Find[...]` but still no results.

Comment: I added a   `If GaRangeID Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Value Found in Cell " & vbCrLf` and effectively, it proved it does not find the value despite being there. The information on AJ has a Header in row 1 if its relevant info.

Comment: Can you update the question with your revised code?  if you're not finding the value then there must be some problem with either the search value of the value in the cell.  If you copy/paste the value from your code into a cell does it get found?

Comment: If you did find the value `GaRangeID.Offset(0, -21).Range("A1")` is not a valid range address.  The `Range(“A1”)` part is invalid.

Comment: @DarrellH - it's not invalid - you can have a range which is relative to another.  It serves no useful purpose here though:  e.g. `Range("D3").Range("A1")` is just `Range("D3")`

Comment: I tryed copy pasting the string of text andthe control+f found it just fine so that wasnt the problem, I just updated the code (once again). I know I started working with VBA just yesterday but this... Im at a loss.

Comment: Is ModeloAnalisis.xlsm the workbook containing your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to offer except to simplify your code a bit and use `xlValues` instead of `xlFormulas` for the `LookIn` parameter

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim f As Range
    Dim WBModeloA1 As Worksheet
    Dim WBModeloA2 As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, rngSearch As Range

    'use "ThisWorkbook" if it's where your code lives
    Set WBModeloA1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cartera 1")
    Set WBModeloA2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cartera 3")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'the sheet you're searching

    'define a range to search
    Set rngSearch = wsData.Range(wsData.Range("AJ1"), _
                                 wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "AJ").End(xlUp))

    'if you have multiple of these following blocks you really need a loop

    Set f = rngSearch.Find(what:="WarrantyPrefA Total", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        WBModeloA1.Range("E67") = f.Offset(0, -3).Value / 1000
        WBModeloA2.Range("H91") = f.Offset(0, -21).Value / 1000
    End If

    Set f = rngSearch.Find(what:="WarrantyPrefB Total", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        WBModeloA1.Range("E65") = f.Offset(0, -3).Value / 1000
        WBModeloA2.Range("H90") = f.Offset(0, -21).Value / 1000
    End If

End Sub
```